# Functions and parenthesis in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I don't understand how all those f() function work, can someone explain why it prints two '1', I know it prints '1' for every '()' after f(f), but I don't know why.

```js
function f(y) {
  let x = y;
  var i = 0;
  return () => {
    console.log(++i);
    return x(y);
  };
}
f(f)()();
```

And why does the 'i' doesn't increase?

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't look like something from the "real world". More like a curiosity, a tongue-twister. I don't understand how this works and I don't mind because I'll never use this kind of twisted things in a real life scenario.

Comment: Notice that `x ≡ y ≡ f`. And you're calling each `() => { console.log(++i); … }` that is created by them only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function f(y) {
  let x = y;
  var i = 0;
  return () => {
    console.log(++i);
    return x(y);
  };
}
f(f)()();
```

is equivalent to

```
function f() {
  var i = 0;
  return () => {
    console.log(++i);
    return f();
  };
}
const t1 = f();
const t2 = t1();
t2();
```

is equivalent to

```
function f() {
  var i = 0;
  return () => {
    console.log(++i);
  };
}
const t1 = f();
t1();
const t2 = f();
t2();
```

If you did call each of `t1` or `t2` multiple times instead of just once, you'd increment the `i` from the respective closure some more. But if you instead just chain them, they call `f` again and initialise a new `var i = 0` for a different closure.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `f(y)` function essentially calling `y` onto itself. Executing `f(y)` would return a **new** function, which when executed, would execute `x(y)` and return the results.

To reduce the confusion, it's just calling `f(f)` for each `f()` you executed in this example, as `x === y` and `y === f`. The important part of why `i` never seems to increase, is that every execution creates a new `i`.

What happens in behind are:

```js
    f(f)()();
    // is same as 
    const f1 = f(f);
    const f2 = f1();
    const f3 = f2();
    // f(f) would execute first, and returns () => {
    //     console.log(++i);
    //     return x(y);  // which is same as returning f(f) in this example
    // }
```

Notice that executing `f(f)` returns `x(y)` which `x(y)` **seems** to be equal to `f(f)`. Seems as it is similar in code, but different instance. Another point is that `i` was never carried to this new function, nor are shared to the other instances. Each `f(f)` creates a new `i`, never passed to the next function.

Answer (score 0):

Let's name the function at line 4 , function A.

return result of function f() is function A.(at line 4 you define a function, you don't call it.)

the body of A is gonna be this and since you use those variables in an inner function, they are not gonna be exposed(i = 0, x = y = f ):

```
   function A(){
     console.log(++i);
     return x(y);
```

so what you have now is: A()().

First parenthesis: A() prints a '1' and returns result of f(f) which is function A.(the first i is exposed and a new i is created)

Second parenthesis : A is executed like I said and return another A, since there are no any parenthesis left, there is no more call.

Answer (score 0):

You declare in `f` always a new `i`.

Instead, you could store the count into a property of the function itself.

```js
function f(y) {
    let x = y;
    f.i = f.i || 0;

    return () => {
        console.log(++f.i);
        return x(y);
    };
}

f(f)()()();
```